# Spring Cloud + Ribbon + Eureka (service registry) and Relative URLs (rels)

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix, netflix-eureka

If I do a call to the autowired RestTemplate it works like a charm:

GET on http://localhost:18990/microservice2/ (service registry):

```
{
    "_links":  {
        "hl:echo":  { "href": "http://localhost:18989/microservice2/echo?echoMessage={echoMessage}",  "templated": true },
        "curies": 
        [ {
                        "href": "/microservice2/generated-docs/api-guide.html#resources-{rel}",
                        "name": "hl",
                        "templated": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

From micro service 1(calling micro service 2 using the RestTemplate):

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
URI targetUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://microservice2")
    .path("/microservice2/echo")
    .queryParam("echoMessage", "echoMessage")
    .build()
    .toUri();
EchoMessageResource response = restTemplate.getForObject(targetUrl, EchoMessageResource.class);
```

**OK**

Ribbon does use Eureka to get to the real server behind the scenes.

If I add a rel then it does NOT work. I get a 404.

FROM:

```
URI targetUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://microservice2")
    .path("/microservice2/echo")
    .queryParam("echoMessage", "echoMessage")
    .build()
    .toUri();
```

TO:

```
URI targetUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://microservice2")
    .path("/microservice2/hl:echo")
    .queryParam("echoMessage", "echoMessage")
    .build()
    .toUri();
EchoMessageResource response = restTemplate.getForObject(targetUrl, EchoMessageResource.class);
```

KO
**404**

What is the way to use a rel ? In my example hl:echo.

Comment: does the path `/microservice2/hl:echo` really resolve to anything?

Comment: @spencergibb:It doesn't. It is coming from the IndexController making usage of ResourceSupport.For example:
`resource.add(ParameterizedControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(methodOn(EchoController.class).doEcho("", null)).withRel(ECHO_REL));` But if the RestTemplate + Ribbon + Eureka give me some magic, they should support the fact that I pass a REL. [Spring Hateoas Client side support doc here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.19.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#client)

Comment: Then the answer is no, spring cloud doesn't know anything about spring hateoas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. As The [Spring Hateoas Client side support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.19.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#client) documentation does not make any reference to Ribbon, I make the assumption that Spring Hateoas does not support Ribbon at all.